# UIView not updating correctly

Tags: ios, swift

[image: The purple bar is "usedBar" and the gray one is "unusedBar"]

I have this strange issue where I want to update the UIView width but it only updates when the new width value if smaller, let's say UIView.width = 100. If new width = 80 the view updates, if it's 120 the view doesn't update.

The new value is fetched from core data.

No storyboard involved


P.s. I noticed that Xcode creates two constraints with the previous value and the new value at the same time and it breaks the one with the new value. But I can't understand why it creates two constraints.

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ef28a0 usedBar.right == unusedBar.right - 147.5   (active, names: usedBar:0x1029110c0, unusedBar:0x102911220 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ef7570 usedBar.right == unusedBar.right - 73.75   (active, names: usedBar:0x1029110c0, unusedBar:0x102911220 )>

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280ef7570 usedBar.right == unusedBar.right - 73.75   (active, names: usedBar:0x1029110c0, unusedBar:0x102911220 )>
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var width: CGFloat?
    let usedBar = UIView()

    var captionCount: CGFloat = 0
    var captionUsed: CGFloat = 0
    var unused: CGFloat = 0
    var captionsUsedNumber: [Bool] = [false]

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        fetchCaptions()
        width = ((scrollView.frame.width - 80) / captionCount) * unused
        configureNumbers()
    }

    func configureNumbers() {
        captionsView.addSubview(usedBar)
        usedBar.backgroundColor = .bluePurple()
        usedBar.anchors(top: captionTitleLabel.bottomAnchor, left: captionsView.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 12, paddingLeft: 20, width: width, height: 20)
    }

    func fetchCaptions() {        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Caption")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            if result.count > 0 {
                captionCount = CGFloat(result.count)
                captionUsed = CGFloat(captionsUsedNumber.count)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.anchors()

```
func anchors(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, 
right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, paddingTop: CGFloat? = 0, paddingLeft: CGFloat? = 0, paddingBottom: CGFloat? = 0, 
paddingRight: CGFloat? = 0, width: CGFloat? = nil, height: CGFloat? = nil) {

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop!).isActive = true
        }

        if let left = left {
            leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft!).isActive = true
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom!).isActive = true
        }

        if let right = right {
            rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight!).isActive = true
        }

        if let width = width {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }

        if let height = height {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        }
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSV8j.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqzp6.jpg
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. From the code you've shown, neither `func` is being called from anywhere. Assuming they *are* being called, we also don't know what your `usedBar.anchors(top: ...` is doing. Are you getting any layout warnings / errors in debug console?

Comment: @DonMag I update the code and I noticed that the right anchor constraint is created twice

Comment: *"I noticed that Xcode creates two constraints"* -- well, *XCode* doesn't do that... something in your code is doing it. Post your `.anchors()` code, so we can see what that's doing. It may help if you also show an image of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DonMag I added the code and the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a slight misunderstanding of how constraints work.

When you do something like this (in your func):

```
widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
```

You are not setting ***THE*** width constraint. Instead, you are ***adding*** a width constraint. If you call that func again, you are adding ***another*** width constraint. You're also adding additional top, left and height constraints, but since you are not changing those values, you don't get any conflicts... but you still get extras.

While your "helper" func can save some repetitive code, right now it's causing issues.

You *could* edit the func to first remove any existing constraints, then add new ones... but that can lead to other issues (such as constraints which are relied on by other views).

In your specific case, since the only constraint you want to change is the width constraint, a better approach would be to create the constraint as a class property (var), and update its `.constant` property when you want it to change.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other ways to do this, but for me the *easiest* is to create two arrays and toggle between them. And *yes*, I'm saying *do not* use `setActive` when setting this up.

Let's say you want a view's width to change, and that *normally* you'd have this:

```
myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

But now you wish to have the width go from 150 to 300. Create two arrays, move the width constraint into it, and `activate` and/or `deactivate` accordingly:

```
// declare the arrays

var growTheWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var shrinkTheWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint]()


// this can be done in viewDidLoad, just make sure the view exists in the hierarchy

growTheWidth.append(myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300))
shrinkTheWidth.append(myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150))
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(shrinkTheWidth)

// these two functions will change the width and animate

func growWidth() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(shrinkTheWidth)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(growTheWidth)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
func shrinkWidth() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(growTheWidth)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(shrinkTheWidth)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
```

Notes:

- Sequence matters. If you activate before deactivating, the layout engine will see conflicts and act in unexpected ways.
- Remember to remove the `isActive` constraint I have in the original set of constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XIB or StoryBoard with Autolayout you will update the constraint not the frame.

You can bind the autolayout to your code like this:
[image]

**Remember delete the weak prefix or the value of your constraint will be always nil.**

```
@IBOutlet var viewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint
```

Now you can edit your view with constraint like this:

```
self.viewWidth.constant = 120
```

I hope I've helped!

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. Also, the OP's code does not show `@IBOutlet`, so this is probably not the answer.

Comment: @DonMag look at his code. Hi has many references of views that is not like `@IBOutlet` and are not in the code:
`usedBar `
`captionsView `
`scrollView `